# Filter my result by multiple selects/dropdowns which will accept multiple value each

Tags: sql, sql-server, rest, knex.js

I have multiple dropdowns

1. Province
2. District
3. Tehsil

All can select multiple values and by default select all.

Now I want to write an efficient SQL query to get work done with one. I'm thinking to use `where col in ()` statement but when I pass no value it causes the error.

What would be a better way to accomplish the results given.

*updating on request for more information is required*

I'm developing one dashboard, in which my charts need to be reactive with multiple dropdowns (filters) which select multiple capabilities, and I assume `where col in ()` clause can support me. The only issue is while using this clause that it can't be empty due to which data fetching from SQL server is not possible when no filter is applied.

Comment: You need to provide additional detail - as it is we have no idea what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by reading this article [arrays-in-sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)

e.g: province = [1,2,3], district = [1,2,3]
first convert province and district into string like province = '1,2,3'
create procedure with params like following

`CREATE PROC myFilterTable ( @province AS VARCHAR ( 50 ) = NULL,@district AS VARCHAR ( 50 ) = NULL ) AS BEGIN
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        myTable 
    WHERE
        ( @province IS NULL OR province_id IN ( SELECT CONVERT ( INT, VALUE ) FROM string_split ( @province, ',' ) ) ) 
    AND ( @district IS NULL OR district_id IN ( SELECT CONVERT ( INT, VALUE ) FROM string_split ( @district, ',' ) ) ) 
END`

Now execute:
`exec myFilter '1,2', '1,3'`